# Clear Memory after holoviews and bokeh plot (during loop)

Tags: python, plot, memory, bokeh, holoviews

I try to export many holoviews plots as png in a loop. My problem is, that after the export of a singular image, the memory is not freed and so, after some iterations, the process kills itself or my pc freezes because the RAM overloads (OOM).

Here is a code that reproduces the problem. I found out, that "df_test.hvplot()" by itself clears the memory like it should, but as son as "hv.render()" is used the memory usage starts to increase without freeing.

In the code there are all my approaches i found online to clean up at the end of the loop, but none of them work.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
from bokeh.io import export_png
import bokeh

import gc


print(f"holoviews version: {hv.__version__}")
print(f"bokeh version: {bokeh.__version__}")
print(f"pandas version: {pd.__version__}")

# Directory (not necessary for testing)
directory_name = 'path_testfolder/'
export_name = 'test'


df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.5, size =(80_000_000, 2)), columns=['x', 'y'])
for i in range(100):
    # Create Plot
    p1 = df_test.hvplot(kind="scatter", x="x", y="y", rasterize=True, datashade=True, width=800, height=800)
    p1_bokeh = hv.render(p1)
    
    # Export
    # file_out_path = directory_name + "/" + export_name + "_" + str(i) + ".png"
    # a = export_png(p1_bokeh, filename=file_out_path, height=800, width=800)
    
    # Clear Memory (Apporaches)
    p1_bokeh.renderers = []
    p1_bokeh = None
    p1 = None
    del p1_bokeh
    del p1
    # del a
    
    bokeh.io.curdoc().clear()  
    bokeh.io.state.State().reset()
    bokeh.io.reset_output()
    
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: I'd suggest seeing if you can reproduce a situation with pure Bokeh, and then file and issue on the appropriate tracker (if it's only when `hvplot` is used then it should be filed on he `hvplot` issue tracker).